# What's the best web accessibility option for Add to Cart e-commerce experience?

Tags: accessibility

We're building our website to adhere to ADA compliance and make it accessible for all the best way we can.  We're trying to find a way to notify the end user when they click "Add to Cart" button when adding a product to their shopping cart.

Somebody recommended doing a popup after the click, but I don't believe that's the best experience.  Can anyone recommend some options for us?

Answer (score 0):

A small, non-modal popup notification is not a crazy idea, just make sure you use an aria-live region, so that the notification text will be announced by screen readers.

Also, consider whether you will need other kinds of notification and make a general solution.